# How to slove this trigonemetry problem

Tags: trigonometry

How would I solve this trigonometry problem step by step? I don't know how to solve this. [Photo of Problem](https://i.stack.imgur.com/EmSro.jpg)

$$\cos^2\bigg(\frac{\pi}{8}\bigg)+\cos^2\bigg(\frac{7\pi}{8}\bigg)+\cos^2\bigg(\frac{3\pi}{8}\bigg)+\cos^2\bigg(\frac{5\pi}{8}\bigg)$$

Comment: What have you tried so far?

Comment: using the identity $\cos^2(\theta)=\frac{1+\cos(2\theta)}{2}$ will give you angles that are multiples of $\frac{\pi}{4}$

Comment: Slove? Trigonemetry??

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The identity $\cos^2(\theta)=\frac{1+\cos(2{\theta)}}{2}$ should be most helpful since it leaves angles of multiples of $\frac{\pi}{4}$:

$$\cos^2\bigg(\frac{\pi}{8}\bigg)+\cos^2\bigg(\frac{7\pi}{8}\bigg)+\cos^2\bigg(\frac{3\pi}{8}\bigg)+\cos^2\bigg(\frac{5\pi}{8}\bigg)$$

=$$\frac{1+\cos\big(\frac{\pi}{4}\big)}{2}+\frac{1+\cos\big(\frac{7\pi}{4}\big)}{2}+\frac{1+\cos\big(\frac{3\pi}{4}\big)}{2}+\frac{1+\cos\big(\frac{5\pi}{4}\big)}{2}$$
=$$\frac{1}{2}\bigg(4+\frac{\sqrt2}{2}+\frac{\sqrt2}{2}-\frac{\sqrt2}{2}-\frac{\sqrt2}{2}\bigg)=2$$

Comment: thanks for teach me cotton Headed.I got it.

Comment: No problem, glad I could help